# How to avoid Extra condition while Drools rule sheet is converted in rules?

Tags: drools

In this Drools sheet I am comparing a class variable with a variable of another class variable but the rule converted are not as expected. Is there a way to do this...

[image]

One thing is creating a problem and it is when this excel sheet is converted into rules the condition where I check **`stdId in college class is equals to id of Student class`** i.e. third column, the rule is generated as follows-

```
$c2: College(stdId == $s.id == "x")
```

The =="x" part is undesirable and creating trouble while running the rules.
What should be done to remove the extra undesired part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third column can be written as

```
CONDITION
$c2: College(stdId==$s.id)/*$param*/
match student id
x
x
...
```

The x is required to trigger insertion of the conditional expression from row 2.